# Using __FILE__ and __LINE__ in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, macros

If __ FIL E__ and __ LINE __ are parameters of a recursive function, is there any way to keep the values of __ FILE __ and __ LINE __ the same throughout all recursions of the function. From my own attempts, you can't strcpy the file name. Also, after the first recursion, the __ FILE __ and __ LINE __ change to the file and line number the recursive function appears at.

For example, in main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "recurse.c"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    recurse(2);
    return 0;
}
```

in recurse.c

```
#define recurse( x ) test( x,__FILE__,__LINE__ )

void test(int num, char* filename, int line){
    if(num > 0)
        test(num - 1, filename, line);
    }
}
```

I want the filename and line to correspond to the function call in main and not the function call in the recursion but doing it this way does not seem possible. I don't even think it is possible but maybe I am missing something.

I would like to make it clear that this is not the code I am using, I just made this up on the spot to detail my question so if there are any big errors I apologize. It isn't supposed to do anything, just help explain my question.

Comment: These are not variables, learn what the preprocessor does, try some code first!

Comment: If you want the line and filename of `"main.cpp"` to be in all the calls as-written the only think you're missing that I can see is `const` for the `char *`. If you want the *first* one to be from `main.cpp` and subsequent to be from the file `test()` is in, the recursive call needs to use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` as well.(i.e. don't forward the `filename` and `line` parameters). And stop `#include`-ing .c/.cpp files. its a bad habit.

Comment: Since `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are resolved only once, during preprocessing, they will actually only *appear* once in your 'recursive' function. Your wording suggests you believe they will appear multpile times, "as many times as `recursive` is called".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are substituted in `recurse` itself. You should directly call `test` from `main` instead:

```
test(2, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```